# Which collection type should I use to store a bunch of hashes?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a bunch of long strings which I have to manipulate. They can occur again and again and I want to ignore them if they appear twice. I figured the best way to do this would be to hash the string and store the list of hashes in some sort of ordered list with a fast lookup time so that I can compare whenever my data set hands me a new string.

Requirements:

- Be able to add items (hashes) to my collection
- Be able to (quickly) check whether a particular hash is already in the collection.
- Not too memory intensive. I might end up with ~100,000 of these hashes.

I don't need to go backwards (key -> value) if that makes any difference.

Any suggestions on which .NET data type would be most efficient?

Comment: Since you need to store a set of hashes, `HashSet` might be your best choice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I figured the best way to do this would be to hash the string and store the list of hashes in some sort of ordered list with a fast lookup time so that I can compare whenever my data set hands me a new string.

No, don't do that. Two reasons:

- Hashes only tell you if two values *might* be the same; they don't tell you if they *are* the same.
- You'd be doing a lot of work which has already been done for you.

Basically, you should just keep a `HashSet<String>`. That should be fine, have a quick lookup, and you don't need to implement it yourself.

The downside is that you *will* end up keeping all the strings in memory. If that's a problem then you'll need to work out an alternative strategy... which may indeed end up keeping just the hashes in memory. The exact details will probably depend on where the strings come from, and what sort of problem it would cause if you got a false positive. For example, you could keep an MD5 hash of each string, as a "better than just `hashCode`" hash - but that would still allow an attacker to present you with another string with the same hash. Is that a problem? If so, a more secure hash algorithm (e.g. SHA-256) might help. It still won't *guarantee* that you end up with different hashes for different strings though.

If you really want to be sure, you'd need to keep the hashes in memory but persist the actual string data (to disk or a database) - then when you've got a *possible* match (because you've seen the same hash before) you'd need to compare the stored string with the fresh one.

If you're storing the hashes in memory, the best approach will depend on the size of hash you're using. For example, for just a 64-bit hash you could use a `Long` per hash and keep it in a `HashSet<Long>`. For longer hashes, you'd need an object which can easily be compared etc. At that point, I suggest you look at [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and its [`HashCode`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.html) class, along with the factory methods in [<s>`HashCodes`</s>](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashCodes.html) (Deprecated since Guava v16).

Comment: The average length of a string is about 280 character so if I keep them all in memory (all 100,000 of them) it will be bad. If there is a hash collision, all it means is that I do some work on a string twice (or several times), but it's not that processor intensive. ie: I'm trying to save myself duplicating my work 20-30 times and in the occasional cases of a collision, it's no big deal.

Comment: @User2400: At about 600 bytes per string, you'd still only use about 60MB to keep all the strings in memory. That's really not a lot of memory by today's standards. Are you on a particularly low-powered system where you can't afford that? See my edits for further thoughts though.

Comment: Good point. I can't guarantee how small the strings will be (might occasionally be 3 or 4 times larger), but youe point is a good one and will probably save me a lot of hassle. HashSet it is!

Answer (score 2):

Use a set.

[`ISet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) interface is implemented by e.g. [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

`Add` and `Contains` are expected O(1), unless you have a really poor hashing function, then the worst case is O(n).